# Spring Integration outbound gateway with poller

Tags: spring, spring-integration

Below is outbound http gateway configured with headers but is not getting triggered continuously when I add poller. It just gets triggered once and stops.

```
<int:inbound-channel-adapter channel="fooinfotrigger.channel" expression="''">
    <int:poller fixed-delay="5000"></int:poller>
</int:inbound-channel-adapter>

<int:channel id="fooinfo.channel">
    <int:queue capacity="10"/>
</int:channel>

<int:channel id="fooinfotrigger.channel"></int:channel>

<int:chain input-channel="fooinfotrigger.channel" output-channel="fooinfo.channel">       

    <int:header-enricher>
        <int:header name="Authorization" value="...." />
        <int:header name="Content-Type" value="...." />
    </int:header-enricher>

    <int-http:outbound-gateway id="fooHttpGateway"
        url="https://foo.com/v1/services/foo?status=active"
        http-method="GET"
        expected-response-type="java.lang.String"
        charset="UTF-8"
        reply-timeout="5000">
    </int-http:outbound-gateway>

    <int:transformer method="transform" ref="fooResourcesTransformer"/>

</int:chain>

<bean id="fooResourcesTransformer" class="com.foo.FooTransformer" />
```

Answer (score 0):

The `fixed-delay` is an option to determine the time **after** the finish of the previous task. In your case the `poll`.

Since you affirm that it

> gets triggered once and stops.

Looks like you don't finish your work somehow on the `dealinfo.channel` and don't return the control to the `TaskScheduler` and, therefore, don't free the thread for something else.

We really should see and understand your logic after that `<chain>` and with a subscribers on that `dealinfo.channel`.

Or... maybe your REST Service just doesn't return response at all. Independently of that `reply-timeout="5000"`.

Comment: Yes agree with you. When the REST service fails with 401 Http Status Error, it re-triggers correctly but when it is successful with 200 Http Status it does not re-trigger. I copied over similar example at this gist which also has the same problem https://gist.github.com/krishnaaravacadreon/3b22ff9a33c3fada2500d76789cee817

Comment: M-m-m. On the other hand that test-case just exits after the first result receiving. So, that is fully the truth that you may have only one poll during that testing.